# Trying to remove a name from columns in a dataset (csv file) then recreate the dataset

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

I have a big dataset of columns filled with names of people applying to different companies-- each company ranks the people on which ones they want (not all the same people applied to each company. When a person gets manually assigned to a company they must be removed from each companies rankings, so I'm writing a function to do that. I can get the people to be removed from each column but I'm struggling to put the data back properly-- it formats the original columns into rows.

This is what I've currently written:

```
def delete_names(student_name, dataset):
    for col in dataset.columns:
        company_ranks = dataset[col].tolist()        
        if student_name in company_ranks:
            company_ranks.remove(student_name)   
    np.transpose(company_ranks)
```

I tried using the transpose function but I don't think that's the right thing to use for this.

Comment: Can you add a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with example inputs as well?

Comment: Looks like you need `dataset.mask(dataset == student_name)`